# How is the implementation different from the Three.js example?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to repeat the example, but using react-three-fiber.

Link to example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_lines_sphere.html (so far only the init method, no animation)

My code:

```
const Sphere = () => {
const vertices: number[] = [];
const scalar = 450;

const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

for(let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
    vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;

    vertex.normalize();
    vertex.multiplyScalar(scalar);
    vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
}

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

const parameters = [[ 0.25, 0xff7700, 1 ], [ 0.5, 0xff9900, 1 ], [ 0.75, 0xffaa00, 0.75 ], [ 1, 0xffaa00, 0.5 ], [ 1.25, 0x000833, 0.8 ], [ 3.0, 0xaaaaaa, 0.75 ], [ 3.5, 0xffffff, 0.5 ], [ 4.5, 0xffffff, 0.25 ], [ 5.5, 0xffffff, 0.125 ]];

return (
    <mesh>
        {
            parameters.map((pGroup, index) => {
                return (
                    <lineSegments
                        key={index}
                        geometry={geometry}
                        scale={new THREE.Vector3(pGroup[0], pGroup[0], pGroup[0])}
                        rotation={new THREE.Euler(undefined, Math.random() * Math.PI, undefined)}
                    >
                        <lineBasicMaterial color={pGroup[1]} opacity={pGroup[2]} />
                    </lineSegments>
                );
            })
        }
    </mesh>
); };
```

Example result:[image: example]

My result: [image]

For some reason, everything is drawn with one line. And, as I noticed, the opacity property does not work. I don't see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why it works this way, but I just moved this code into a separate function

```
const createGeometry = (scalar: number) => {

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const vertices = [];

const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

for ( let i = 0; i < 1500; i ++ ) {

    vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    vertex.normalize();
    vertex.multiplyScalar(scalar);

    vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

    vertex.multiplyScalar(Math.random() * 0.09 + 1);

    vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

}

geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

return geometry; };
```